# Memory Limit Hit

Tags: railstutorial.org, cloud9-ide

Memory Limit Hit following rubyrailstutorial.org

Hi,

I am following the tutorial on [Ruby Rails Tutorial](https://www.railstutorial.org/) and I am using the [Cloud9 IDE](https://c9.io/) however I keep getting a "Memory Limit Hit" when running through the tutorial.  I am using the free tier which comes with 512MB Ram which is constantly in the red zone.

I have tried killing some processes, but as soon as I start back on the tutorial I keep getting the error.

Thanks

Michael

Comment: Can you go to the Disk/Memory/CPU menu near the top right, click on 'Show Processes List' and see how many Ruby processes are running. There shouldn't be more than one. If they're there, kill them. Let me know how that goes for you in reducing your memory footprint.

Comment: The above is very helpful and should probably be the answer to this. I killed all the "Ruby" processes and then re-ran the tests and they passed while the memory is now about 20%.

Comment: Mutahhir suggestion in my case reduced memory usage at about 200 MB

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Short answer: Spring has a bug that causes it to use up memory by spawning too many processes.

From your c9 shell, run

```
pkill -9 -f spring
```

and restart your rails server.

Longer answer: He describes a lot about it in Chapter 3 of the tutorial. 
Box 3.4 on this page https://www.railstutorial.org/book/static_pages covers it nicely.

Incidentally, I found that I couldn't simply restart my c9 session...it's really good at persisting the state of your virtual server ... including all of the extra Spring processes.